# PlayOnLinux Missing OpenGL 32 Libraries (nvidia-358, ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: wine, playonlinux, opengl

When launching PlayOnLinux on (x)Ubuntu, nvidia 358: it cannot locate the OpenGL 32bit libraries.

Comment: The Wine package should depend on those libraries. How did you set up PoL? Did you install any of the `wine*` packages? What happens, when you run `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running manually:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32/nvidia-xxx playonlinux`

(*xxx=358 in my case*)

**Optional**: execute using the .desktop icon / applications menu.

run:

`sudo nano /usr/share/applications/PlayOnLinux.desktop`

change Exec to:

`Exec=env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32/nvidia-358 playonlinux %F`